# react native state is updated but functions still using the initial state set at the time of mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my react native functional component, the state gets updated but when I want to use this state inside a function (for e.g, to send data to API), it uses the initial state only.

```
imports...

const Component = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([1,2]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <HeaderRight 
        onPress={() =>
          console.log(ids); // this logs initial state, i.e, [1,2]
          updateIdsToServerViaAPI(); // and therefore I'm unable to update ids using this method
        }
      />
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const updateIdsToServerViaAPI = async () => {} // function that takes updated ids from state.

  const onPress = async () => {
    const newIds = [...ids, 3, 4];
    setIds(newIds);
  }

  const onPressInsideComp = () => {
    console.log(ids);
    // here updated ids gets logged.
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={onPress} />
      {ids.map(id => (
        <Text key={id}>{id}</Text> {\* Here you will see 4 texts after pressing button, that means state gets updated*\}
      )}
      <Button onPress={onPressInsideComp} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Seems like this issue happens only when functions are called inside `useLayoutEffect` or `useEffect` but when I call `onPressInsideComp` from the button inside the component, it logs properly!

**I am badly stuck on this weird issue !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only provided the `navigation` prop in the dependency array of your `useLayoutEffect` wrapper, thus the function is not recreated if the `ids` state changes.

You might want to create a different function, wrapped inside a `useCallback` which gets the `ids` state as a dependency and provide this function in your `useLayoutEffect`.

```js
const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(ids); 
    updateIdsToServerViaAPI();
}, [ids])

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <HeaderRight 
        onPress={() =>
          doSomething(ids)
        }
      />
    });
  }, [navigation, ids, doSomething]);
```

Comment: In my actual code, I was actually doing this but missing one dependency! Lol. but Thanks!

Comment: @Gaurav That's great! I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `console.log(ids)` is resolved at the moment of the function definition, and not at execution time, so it takes the reference you get in the definition `const [ids, setIds} = useState([1,2])`.

Maybe just try to get your ids with a function of state instead of using a variable that has been defined before:

```js
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([1,2]);
  const get_ids = () => this.state.ids;
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <HeaderRight 
        onPress={() =>
          console.log(get_ids());
          updateIdsToServerViaAPI();
        }
      />
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work!

Comment: It's more kind of an example to illustrate the fact of using a function of state, you probably shouldn't paste it like this in your code, maybe you sould adapt it to fit exactly your needs.